# building qt project using visual studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, nmake

I have build a Qt project (qwt) using the vs2013 compiler in Qt creator. When I open the .pro file and look at the build steps I see:

- qmake: qmake.exe qwt.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2013
- Make: nmake.exe in C:\qwt-6.1.2

When I build the project, all goes fine and the project is build without errors. So far so good.

However when I try to build this project using the command line I get errors during the nmake step. I have used the same commands as above (and I'm sure that I'm using the same versions of qmake/nmake).

```
...\QtCore\qglobal.h(38) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
```

My question is, what does Qt do more so that the project does build in Qt creator and not from the command prompt? And how can I copy this behaviour in the command prompt? I'm doing this so I can make a batch file that builds the project (on a machine that does not have Qt creator installed).

Comment: did you open a normal cmd session? To build visual studio stuff on the commandline you should execute the corresponding `vcvars.bat` (vcvars32 or vcvars64) file to setup the environment. Or open the dedicated "VS2013 x64 Native Command Promt" shortcut that does it for you

Comment: No I did not. After I executed the correct .bat file it worked. If you add this answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the Visual Studio compilation environment from the command-line you need to call the `vcvars` batch script to set up the paths correctly.

Either call the `vcvars64.bat` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64` folder (that is for VS2013, you can replace the "12.0" with whatever visual studio version you have).

Or the `vcvars32.bat` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` folder.

Or use the `vcvarsall.bat x86` or `vcvarsall.bat x64` calls for the script in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC`

Alternatively Visual Studio creates shortcuts in the start-menu called along the lines of `VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` which call those scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be that `Qt Creator` has added additional variables into the build environment, which are not presented when you try to compile manually through `cmd`.

If you look within `Qt Creator` under the `Projects` section there's `Build` information. Expand the `Build Environment` information and check to see if there's anything in there different to your machines global environment settings.